# I can't see my photos on my iPad mini from Windows 8

Tags: ipad, photos, windows

Up until recently, I've been able to download the photos and videos off of my iPad mini onto my Windows 8 box. However, the last time I plugged it into the computer, Windows updated the driver that it uses to get at the iPad's files, and now all I see in the Explorer window is an empty Internal Files folder. How do I get at the photos and videos from my PC? I might add that they're all in the camera roll, so according to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32244/93880) answer to another question, I should be able to see them.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPad mini jailbroken or not? Usually I would use iTunes for my photos and videos transferred to computer.

Comment: The iPad isn't jailbroken. As for iTunes, where the heck is the command for transferring photos and videos in there? I have yet to find it. (Apple software seems to get more counterintuitive with each version.)